# SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) - correct upgrading path

Tags: sql-server-2016, upgrade

I've found in my organization VM with SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4532097) - 13.0.5102.14 (X64), which I would like to patch to the latest available version.
Can I just install CU15 (KB4577775) on it or there is more complex path?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's that simple. Applying a cumulative update applies *all the fixes* up to that point. [More info here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/back-to-basics-release-acronyms).